# Android NDK : Aborting. Stop

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I'm trying to call `C++` method in `Java` coding.

I received the `Android NDK : Aborting. Stop` when defined the `Android.mk` file as below :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/ffmpeg.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ffmpeg
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But if I defined like this, it run successfully :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/ffmpeg.so

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

`Questions` :

1 - How to fix this error?

2 - In `Android.mk` file, Can not call `libs/ffmpeg.so` and `ffmpeg.cpp` in the same time?

People who know this,

Please tell me,

Thanks,

p/s : Project structure :

[image]

Comment: `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/ffmpeg.so` ????

Comment: Sorry? What u mean? As image below?

Comment: I mean.. LOCAL_SRC_FILES is expecting the place where the sources file are located, but you make it point to the `.so`. Maybe I am wrong, it is a bit of time that I do not work with ndk, but it looks a bit strange to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When seeing the [`Android.mk structure`](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html).

I think I need change `Android.mk` file like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/ffmpeg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := final_ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_PREBUILTS := libs/ffmpeg.so
#libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The result will help me :

It still be exactly when you need [call the C++ function in C++ file from Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607042/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-calling-c-method-in-c-file-from-java-file?noredirect=1#comment34431151_22607042).