# UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling C++ method in C++ file from Java file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android.mk

It looks like it is the popular problem,

And I still not find out the solution.

`package name` : `app.cloudstringers`

`Java file : Completed.java`

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.d("", "Error : " + e.toString());
    }

}

    // Define native method
public native int getString();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_completed);

    // Call native method
    Log.d("", "" + getString());
```

`C++ file : ffmpeg.cpp`

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_app_cloudstringers_Completed_getString(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
jstring strRet = env->NewStringUTF("HelloWorld from JNI !");
return strRet;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`Android.mk file`

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I run application but still get the error exception `UnsatisfiedLinkError : getString`

People who know the how to fix this problem,

Please tell me,

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Follow @dextor answer. Sorry because I get the mistake. Only thing I need for this question is change from `public native int getString()` to `public native String getString()`.

It works now.

Comment: Post enough of the stack trace to include the messages generated by your attempt to load the library, and the **full** unsatisfied link error.  Also provide the name of the Java file in which the native method is defined.

Comment: And make sure to include e.printStackTrace() in your catch blocks so that you get meaningful error reports.

Comment: try-catch of `System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");` not run. It's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure (didn't actually try), but the only wrong thing I've noticed is the return type of your method declarations.

Java-side

`public native int getString()`

NDK-side

`JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_app_cloudstringers_Completed_getString(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)`

In Java, you have an `int`. On the C-side, you have a `jstring`.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely going to cause problems before the code works, though it may not cause the problem which is posted.